# osmdroid draw polygon on map

Tags: android, dictionary, polygon, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I want to draw something like this:
[gooogle maps example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-autoclose)

but using osmdroid with OpenStreetMaps.

I have a set of GPS points prepared but I cannot find ay working example

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 1):

PathOverlay will not do the job properly: it has been optimized for drawing lines, and this is causing issues when using it for filled polygons (when the polygon is partly inside the view, and partly outside).

You can use the [OSMBonusPack](http://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/) Polgon overlay.

Answer (score 0):

A PathOverlay will give you the polygon.  You may have to extend PathOverlay to create the fill color.